# How do themes provide support for child themes?

Tags: child-theme

One of the requests on themeforest is that themes are required to provide child theme support.

I know what child themes are, although I haven't worked a lot with them, but I would like to know is there something that my theme must have to *support* child themes?

Comment: Was there a problem creating a child theme for your theme? If you know how to create a child theme then you should know everything there is to know?

Comment: I created and it works fine, but I wonder if there is anything more that I need to add or test. If that's all than ok. Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is already an accepted answer, however, I am going to offer a different answer. There are things you need to do to support proper child theme functionality.

First and foremost, work within the [WordPress template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). I have seen themes do strange things and cook up non-standard templating structures. It isn't even necessary to use any of the WordPress theme system to display content if you really really don't want to. Resist the urge to do any of that.

Second, load files that should be replaceable with [`get_template_part()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) and [`locate_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) and not with PHP's `include` or `require`. Files loaded with [`get_template_part()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) and [`locate_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) part can be replaced by child themes. Files loaded by `include` or `require` can't.

Third, use [get_template_directory()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory), [get_template_directory_uri()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri), [get_stylesheet_directory()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory), and [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) appropriately.

You probably also want to register and enqueue your scripts and stylesheets with `wp_register_script`, `wp_enqueue_script`, `wp_register_style` and `wp_enqueue_style`.

If you do those things the theme should be pretty pretty child-theme friendly.

Put another way, if you are doing things right in the first place you shouldn't have to do anything special to have a child-theme friendly theme.

Comment: Exactly. Nothing is more frustrating than working with a theme where styles, scripts and template parts can't be modified by a child theme.

Comment: @ s_ha_dum: well sexplained!

Comment: @Valeka: You should mark this answer as Accepted - such nicely explained by s_ha_dum. Kudos to him.

Comment: Actually I think `include` and `require` need to be used and `get_template_directory()` should be there inside of them, and child themes can modify files required, (or included). Can you please modify your answer a bit.

Comment: You didn't understand my answer @prosti

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, nearly all themes should support a child theme. I've never had to do any thing specific to a parent theme to make it support a child theme. The WordPress Codex has a good overview of child themes. http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes Hope this helps answer your question!