# How do you make your theme Child Theme-able?

Tags: themes, child-theme

I'm sorry if this is an obvious question, but I've tried looking everywhere and can't seem to find an answer.

Are WordPress themes automatically Child Theme-able? Or is there a process to make a theme ready for Child Themes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things have already been discussed [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109637/how-do-themes-provide-support-for-child-themes) I would like to add more

In order to make your theme a good parent you also need to consider in following things:

- make your functions and classes pluggable ie, wrap your theme functions with 
  `function_exists` wrapper so that they can be overridden in child
  pages.

  ```
  if ( ! function_exists( 'theme_entry_date' ) ) :
  function theme_entry_date(){...}
  endif;
  ```
- provide action and filter hooks generously