# Why wp_register_style() is important while I'm using a complete wp_enqueue_style()?

Tags: wp-enqueue-style, wp-register-style

Currently I'm working on a theme, and did some styles and scripts enqueue. When enqueued the scripts, I used `wp_register_script()` first, and then enqueued with `wp_enqueue_script()` - because I got that's the proper way of enqueuing the scripts. But in enqueuing the styles, I used only the `wp_enqueue_style()` with all its parameters. But just now I got [an answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/109654/22728) from s_ha_dum saying that using the `wp_register_style()` would make theme child theme-friendly - I wonder, without the `wp_register_style()` I's using only the `wp_enqueue_style()` and my theme's working fine with the enqueued styles. I enqueued them like:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse20131025_styles' );

function wpse20131025_styles(){

    wp_enqueue_style( 'site-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', '', '', 'screen' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'menu-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/menu.css', '', '', 'screen and (min-device-width: 800px)' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mobile-menu-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/mobile-menu.css', '', '', 'screen and (max-device-width: 799px)' );

}
```

While the `wp_enqueue_style()` has all the parameters that present in `wp_register_style()` (*$handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media*) then why should I repeat them? Or, what exactly the purpose of `wp_register_style()` other than `wp_enqueue_style()`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

First of all let's say that regarding these functions what is valid for styles is exactly valid for scripts, but there are some exceptions to the contrary explained in the answer.

Main difference between `wp_enqueue_*` and respective `wp_register_*` functions, is that the first adds scripts/styles to the queue, the second *prepares* scripts/styles to be added.

You probably already know that, but there is a second difference; `wp_register_*` can be used in every hook, even in an early hook like `init`, but `wp_enqueue_*` should be used on `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook (or `admin_enqueue_scripts` for backend) <sup>1</sup>.

The typical scenario of using both functions is when you want to register scripts/styles on theme init, and then enqueue them conditionally on some pages, e.g.

```
add_action('init', 'my_register_styles');

function my_register_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'style1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style1.css' );
    wp_register_style( 'style2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style2.css' );
    wp_register_style( 'style3', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style3.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_styles' );

function my_enqueue_styles() {
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style3' );
    } elseif ( is_page_template( 'special.php' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style1' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style2' );
    } else {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style1' );
    }
}
```

In this way the conditional enqueuing is more readable and less verbose.

In addition, if you want to enqueue one or more of the registered styles/scripts also in the backend, you can use the registered handle in a function hooking `admin_enqueue_scripts` without having to pass all params again.

Sure this is more useful for scripts, because of `wp_localize_script` that in previous scenario can be called once, after script registration, and then on conditional enqueuing just enqueue the script, even if it is used more than once: this keeps code simpler and DRY.

When you register a script/style and immediately after you enqueue it, it's just an unnecessary task, that actually can be completely avoided:

```
wp_register_style( 'style1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style1.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'style1' );
```

There's no advantage to enqueuing a style (or script) in like this, just use `wp_enqueue_style` with all params of `wp_enqueue_style` and you are done.

Previous sentence is also true regarding the child theme friendship. To overwrite a style in the child theme, when the parent is using `wp_register_style` immediately followed by `wp_enqueue_style`, you have to de-register the style and register again with another URL. If the parent is only using `wp_enqueue_style`, in the child theme you can use [`wp_dequeue_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style) and enqueue the new style, so in the child theme you need 2 lines of code in both cases.

However, what is very child theme friendly is to wrap the functions that enqueue and/or register styles and scripts in a  `if ( ! function_exists(` ... in this way child theme can overwrite parent theme styles and scripts all in one place:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'my_register_styles' ) ) {
    function my_register_styles() {
        wp_register_style( 'style1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style1.css' );
        wp_register_style( 'style2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style2.css' );
        wp_register_style( 'style3', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style3.css' );
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'my_enqueue_styles ') ) {
    function my_enqueue_styles() {
        if ( is_front_page() ) {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'style3' );
        } elseif ( is_page_template( 'special.php' ) ) {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'style1' );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'style2' );
        } else {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'style1' );
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the child theme it's possible to write another `my_register_styles` and/or `my_enqueue_styles` function and change all styles (if needed, of course) without having to deregister/dequeue styles one by one.

---

<sup>1</sup> Here's another difference from scripts and styles: `wp_enqueue_script` can be used in the body of a page (typical use is in a shortcode) and the script will be put in the footer.

Comment: Excellent G.M. nice inner-reviewed the matter so holistic. Kudos to your effort. :)

Comment: Thanks @MayeenulIslam I started answering before toscho marked question as duplicate. Glad it was useful for you, so it probably will be so for others :)

Comment: @gmazzap Incredibly useful, just searched for `wp_register_style vs wp_enqueue_style` and your reply helped me understand the matter thoroughly.

Comment: Great answer, thanks.