# Use wp_enqueue_scripts, not wp_print_styles?

Tags: css, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

Everywhere is said that you need to use `wp_enqueue_scripts()` instead of `wp_print_styles()`.
`wp_print_styles()` is located in `wp-includes/functions.wp-styles.php`.

So what does it mean? What should I change? Where? Why? Can it compromise my theme?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. I you can post more details of the use you are doing of `wp_prit_styles` we can tell you if you should change something or not.

Comment: My problem is simply that some css are not rendered. In the console they appear inline but they are not, so I guess it's because it's ouput directly to the browser via wp_print_styles.

Answer (score 4):

In short, [as of WordPress 3.3](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_print_styles) use `wp_enqueue_scripts` to load JS and CSS. `wp_print_styles` has/had some minor bugs with it (namely, it may include your scripts in the admin as well) - [here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2011/12/12/use-wp_enqueue_scripts-not-wp_print_styles-to-enqueue-scripts-and-styles-for-the-frontend/) and [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19510) are some more details on all of that. It doesn't sound like there's any major security flaws or theme breaking here, just better practice to use `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

Additionally:

- [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) - for enqueuing on the front end
- [login_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/login_enqueue_scripts) - for enqueuing on the login page
- [admin_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) - for enqueuing on admin pages

Answer (score 1):

The other answer confuses the function with the action hook. There is nothing wrong with using the [`wp_print_styles()` ***function***](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_print_styles/) to print a stylesheet link, as long as you've *already* registered/enqueued the stylesheet and know its handle.

(Fun fact: it's the function WP uses under the hood to output the enqueued stylesheets during `wp_head()`.)

The guidance [on the core blog](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2011/12/12/use-wp_enqueue_scripts-not-wp_print_styles-to-enqueue-scripts-and-styles-for-the-frontend/) and in [the Trac ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19510) advises against using the `wp_print_styles` ***hook*** to enqueue a stylesheet. In WP 3.3, this might have caused your custom stylesheet to load in the admin area, but [this was fixed](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/functions.wp-styles.php?rev=19649). Regardless, it's still the wrong hook for registering or enqueuing stylesheets, since it fires *during* the `wp_print_styles()` function.

Generally, you should use `wp_enqueue_style()` since it handles registration & enqueueing (and, as a result, printing the link as part of `wp_head`). All-in-one simplicity.

However, if you need total control over where the stylesheet link is placed (say it needs to go in a specific template part, or wrapped inside `<noscript>` tags), `wp_print_styles()` is the right function to use.

Here's an example of how you might use them all:

```php
// functions.php
function addMainStylesheet(){
  wp_enqueue_style( 'main-styles', 'main.css' );
}
function registerNoscriptStylesheet(){
  // registers the handle, but does not add it to the print queue.
  wp_register_style( 'noscript-styles', 'noscript.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addMainStylesheet' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'registerNoscriptStylesheet' );
```

```php
// header.php

// Fire the `wp_head` hook, which prints the link for main.css
wp_head();
?>
<noscript>
<?php
// Now we'll print the handle we registered earlier
wp_print_styles( 'noscript-styles' );
?>
</noscript>
```

I'd recommend this question for more about the difference between `wp_enqueue_style()` and `wp_register_style()`:
[Why wp_register_style() is important while I'm using a complete wp_enqueue_style()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124354/why-wp-register-style-is-important-while-im-using-a-complete-wp-enqueue-style)