# Can't make wp_enqueue work

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I have this weird problem. Trying to enqueue a CSS file on an existing `functions.php` file and nothing seems to work. This is the pertinent part of the functions file, made by someone else based on TwentySixteen theme :

```
function twentysixteen_scripts() {

    // Add custom fonts, used in the main stylesheet.

    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentysixteen-fonts', twentysixteen_fonts_url(), array(), null );

    // Add Genericons, used in the main stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'genericons', get_template_directory_uri() . '/genericons/genericons.css', array(), '3.4.1' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css', array(), '3.4.1' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-owl', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/owl.carousel.css', array(), '3.4.1' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-owl-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/owl.theme.css', array(), '3.4.1' );



    // Theme stylesheet.

    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentysixteen-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
     if (! is_front_page() || is_single())
    {wp_enqueue_style( 'blog-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . 'full-style.css', array( 'twentysixteen-style' ), '20170410' );}
    // Load the Internet Explorer specific stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentysixteen-ie', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ie.css', array( 'twentysixteen-style' ), '20150930' );
    /* 09.02.2017 */
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/jquery-ui.css', array( 'twentysixteen-style' ), '20150930' );

    /* 09.02.2017 */
    wp_style_add_data( 'twentysixteen-ie', 'conditional', 'lt IE 10' );
    // Load the Internet Explorer 8 specific stylesheet.

    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentysixteen-ie8', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ie8.css', array( 'twentysixteen-style' ), '20151230' );
    wp_style_add_data( 'twentysixteen-ie8', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );
    // Load the Internet Explorer 7 specific stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentysixteen-ie7', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ie7.css', array( 'twentysixteen-style' ), '20150930' );
    wp_style_add_data( 'twentysixteen-ie7', 'conditional', 'lt IE 8' );
    // Load the html5 shiv.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentysixteen-html5', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/html5.js', array(), '3.7.3' );
    wp_script_add_data( 'twentysixteen-html5', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentysixteen-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20151112', true );
    /* 09.02.2017 start */
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-ui.js', array(), '20151112', true );
    //wp_enqueue_script( 'taskCompRegress', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/taskCompRegress.js', array(), '20151112', true );
    if(is_single(556) || is_single(274)){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'UXSalary2014', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/UXSalary2014.js', array(), '20151112', true );
    }
    if(is_single(6440)){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'UXSalary2016', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/UXSalary2016.js', array(), '20170314', true );
    }
    if(is_single(3656)){
        wp_enqueue_script( 'UXSalary.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/UXSalary.js', array(), '20110823', true );
    }

    if(is_single(204)){
        wp_enqueue_script( 'taskCompRegress.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/taskCompRegress.js', array(), '20110321', true );
    }


    if(is_single(274)){
    //wp_enqueue_script( 'UXSalary', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/UXSalary.js', array(), '20151112', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'npsSUSMeanRegress', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/npsSUSMeanRegress.js', array(), '20151112', true );
    }
    if(is_single(458)){
        wp_enqueue_script( 'UXQuiz', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/UXQuiz.js', array(), '20131112', true );
    }
    //wp_enqueue_script( 'UXQuiz', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/UXQuiz.js', array(), '20151112', true );
    if(is_single(3695)){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bs.js', array(), '20151112', true );
    }
    if(is_single(3703)){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'uiProbs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/uiProbs.js', array(), '20151112', true );
     }
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ciquiz', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ciquiz.js', array(), '20151112', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'geoMean', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/geoMean.js', array(), '20151112', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-2.2.4.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js', array(), '20151112', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-3.1.0.min.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js', array(), '20151112', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custSampSize.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custSampSize.js', array(), '20151112', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'actb.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/actb.js', array(), '20151112', true );
    // wp_enqueue_script( 'color-scheme-control', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/color-scheme-control.js', array(), '20151112', true );
    //wp_enqueue_script( 'compSUSRegress', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/compSUSRegress.js', array(), '20151112', true );
    //wp_enqueue_script( 'customize-preview', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/customize-preview.js', array(), '20151112', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'html5', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/html5.js', array(), '20151112', true );
    //wp_enqueue_script( 'keyboard-image-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/keyboard-image-navigation.js', array(), '20151112', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'klm', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/klm.js', array(), '20151112', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myscript.js', array(), '20151112', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myselect2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myselect2.js', array(), '20151112', true );
    //wp_enqueue_script( 'npsMeanRegress', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/npsMeanRegress.js', array(), '20151112', true );

    if(is_single(230))
    {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'npsMeanRegress', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/npsMeanRegress.js', array(), '20151112', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'npsSUSMeanRegress', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/npsSUSMeanRegress.js', array(), '20151112', true );
    }

    wp_enqueue_script( 'organic', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/organic.js', array(), '20151112', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20151112', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-1.10.2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-1.10.2.js', array(), '20151112', true );
    /* 09.02.2017 end */
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom.css', array(), false, '' );


    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
    if ( is_singular() && wp_attachment_is_image() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'twentysixteen-keyboard-image-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/keyboard-image-navigation.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20151104' );
    }
    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentysixteen-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20151204', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentysixteen-jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentysixteen-boot', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentysixteen-owl', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/owl.carousel.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentysixteen-main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'twentysixteen-script', 'screenReaderText', array(
        'expand'   => __( 'expand child menu', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'collapse' => __( 'collapse child menu', 'twentysixteen' ),
    ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentysixteen_scripts' );
```

All of this works. Now, I want to enqueue yet another file. Additionally, I wanted to make it load conditionally, anywhere but front page, but at this point I'd be very happy by making it load at all!

First, I tried the conditional version `(if ! is_front_page...)` but didn't work (I made it work on `header.php`, but I want it to load after everything else). Thinking there might be an error in my code, I tried enqueuing the file just to see it loads.... and nothing. Tried everything I could think of... and nothing.

So, as a last resource, I tried replacing one of the files that actually loads, `custom-style --> css/custom.css`  and as weird as it sounds, it does nothing. Furthermore, if I check the source, even so `css/custom.css` shouldn't be there, it still is. **Just in case: I don't have any cache and I can see any other changes that are not related to this file.**

Finally, I tried to create a different function to enqueue files and nothing, it doesn't work at all.

This is the code I tried to add with no luck:

```
{wp_enqueue_style( 'blog-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . 'full-style.css', array( 'twentysixteen-style' ), '20170410' );}
```

Finally, based on [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124354/why-wp-register-style-is-important-while-im-using-a-complete-wp-enqueue-style/124381#124381) I tried this, which would also help with the conditional part:

```
add_action('init', 'my_register_styles');

function my_register_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'style1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_register_style( 'style2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/full-style.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_styles' );

function my_enqueue_styles() {
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style1' );
    } else {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style2' );
    }
}
```

but as you probably imagine by now.... it didn't work!

## Question(s)

- What is causing this? What am I doing wrong?
- Is there a way to make the stylesheet load on header.php AFTER the enqueued scripts?

Comment: Hi, do you have debugging turned on? And if you inspect your browser do you have any errors? And maybe what is your site?

Comment: I had to make an edit to my answer. I originally suggested  `wp_dequeue_script()`, but I meant to use  `wp_dequeue_style()` so be sure to user the correct one if you are testing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I meant to refer to [`wp_dequeue_style()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style)

You have to dequeque (unregister) the scripts or styles that you wish to replace before replacing them or the new parameters won't be accepted. Use `wp_dequeue_style()`. Also, as it says in the description for [`wp_dequeue_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script), hook it with a late [priority](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/#parameters) (100), so that it is after the script was enqueued.

I believe your function `my_enqueue_styles()` is where you would want to make use of `wp_dequeue_style()` just before `wp_enqueue_style()` is used. Something like this:

```
function my_enqueue_styles() {
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        wp_dequeue_style( 'style1' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style1' );
    } else {
        wp_dequeue_style( 'style1' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style2' );
    }
}
```

Then add the integer `100` as an argument in your action hook.
`add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_styles', 100 );`

Deque any other scripts or styles you wish to enqueue that have already been enqueued.

Comment: thank you, that really made it! I can't vote up, but I'd give you 1000 votes, ha ha!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are changing the correct functions.php file? You can also check if there is any other header-{xxx}.php in your theme which may be preventing the enqueue scripts from triggering.

One last thing you can try is call the wp_enqueue_style() in the template file (like the page.php or a page-template.php). Doing so will load that style only when that template page is requested.