# Widget edit and add in any page

Tags: php, widgets, css

So I have this [site](http://workteamfun.ro/wp2/) and on the bottom of the site you can see the map and search. I have 2 problems with that:

1. The search if offset not in line with the other elements.
2. I want/need it to be full width just like in the Take a Quick and FREE Tour page (scroll down a bit to see the map).

The thing is the theme does not allow me to add widgets where I want in the site only specific pages. The second link is the template for the "homepage" after I select this template I can't edit like the rest of the pages only add or delete widgets and the other problem is with the white space between the picture and the start of the blue background where the map is on the first link.

I tried to take the code from the page with the map widget and paste it in the area with blue which is a call to action div in all pages and templates. This is the [code](http://textuploader.com/5ce27)(hopefully it's the full code).

Is there a way to add widgets anywhere in a site, is there a short-code mapper or a plugin, I found a few plugins but none with the desired result.

Comment: Plugin recommendation is off topic. You may want to edit that bit out - is there any code you've tried to achieve this? (not just a dump of the page, the code that generates it maybe?)

Comment: problem is ...this theme i`m using is pretty shit and with a very small number of customization options ...there are 3 templates with the map widget but all 3 are different and have different code from what i saw after editing the page with raw code ...i just need the one in [here](http://workteamfun.ro/wp2/privacy-policy/) middle of the page ...

Comment: or maybe there is a way to add any widget in any page ..thing is the customizer from the theme [see pic](http://postimg.org/image/kc5rb10p5/) and [pic2](http://postimg.org/image/hges4n86p/) thinking maybe some editing in the customize-theme.php might work ..dunno ..i`m here to learn :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Search issue:
   You have label and br tags above search_keywords and search_location input fields. You can eater remove them in theme or set display: none; in css style for them.

Css eg:

```
.search_keywords label,
.search_keywords br,
.search_location label,
.search_location br { 
    display: none;
}
```

2. If you want to make map full width just like your 'quick tour screen', you need to move ***filters jobify_widget_map-2*** from .container class in footer.

[image]

Comment: 1-st problem is fixed ..thank you for that :D 
Problem 2 ..can you please be more specific on the second matter ....shoould i copy this bit 
<section id="filters jobify_widget_map-2" class="homepage-widget filters jobify_widget_map"> into footer.php  ?

Comment: and also how could i make the white space between the elements from the blue area to the picture

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to add widgets anywhere in a site,...

No. Widgets are added to sidebars. Sidebars are displayed by the theme. That sidebar code is hard coded into the theme. [There are examples in the Codex.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar#Examples)

There is no way to "map" a sidebar to just anywhere you want in the theme. What that would mean would be opening the PHP template files programatically and editing the code into them, or capturing the output and parsing the page before it renders (very hard and very resource intensive).

There *might be* hooks in the theme that you can use. SOmething like:

```
function add_my_sidebar() {
  dynamic_sidebar( 'my-special-sidebar' );
}
add_action('some_theme_hook','add_my_sidebar'):
```

But is unlikely you'll find the hooks you want where you want them.

If this is important to you, [make a child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). Hopefully, [your theme is written proper to support that](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/109654/21376).

Comment: thx for the reply ...sadly i don`t know how to make a child theme ...how about if there is a way to edit inside the theme editor to add more options in the widget area as the pictures i posted Top ....for example post widgets in the content area ....or something ?

Comment: You don't want to hack a theme that you don't maintain. Your changes would be overwritten when the theme updates. Read the Codex page I linked to. A child theme may not be too hard.